# Plug identification DB25 style

Tags: connector, identification, plug

I would like to identify this connector in order to buy it
This is the same size as DB25 but this is not with pin like on the parallel port [image]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/az0Tz.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Looks like a 50-pin connector which was used for SCSI way back in the day ...

Comment: Could be something like one of these [Hirose DX](https://www.mouser.com/Hirose-Electric/I-O-Connectors/DX-Series/_/N-1z0jmg3Z1yrnlZ1z0ykui) connectors.

Comment: Awful picture - I'm sure you could have done far better.

Comment: When taking a picture for connector identification, please put a ruler next to the thing so that there's a way for us to determine its physical size as accurately as possible. There's a few 0.100"/2.54mm whiteboards in the background but they're too distorted to work as a size reference. From the photo it's hard to tell whether it's a Centronics (IEEE-488 or Parallel Printer or SCSI-1) or a Hirose DX, both look similar but the Hirose DX is a bit smaller.

Comment: If you go to the OEM web page and find the servo drives information, there should be a sub link to cable connection data. https://www.amazon.com/3000rpm-Absolute-Encoder-JASD2002-20B-60JASM5022K-20B/dp/B077WXZPD9

Comment: You should measure the dimension over the latches or between the first/last pin centers that corresponds to the data sheet @MarkU posted.

Comment: Again, measure the dimensions **shown on the drawing posted** - don't measure two other random dimensions not shown on the drawing, as you won't learn much from that.  Center-to-center measurements should be a familiar concept; if not, take time to understand them now, as those decimal places on your fancy calipers are not meaningful if you do not position the jaws in the correct place.  If you can't hold the calipers and the camera, take a proper measurement and report the dimension in text rather than as a picture.

Comment: 47mm is between center hole.

Comment: Try to measure the actual centers, or between the left or right edges.  Chances are you'll find it's actually 46.45 mm.

Comment: Yes I measured between first and last pin and have the same dimension as answer below. Thank all of you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Hirose DX20-50P(55) or DX40-50P-55. Hard to tell from your photo but I think it looks smaller than Centronics. Suggest you check the measurements in the catalog to confirm.

[image: snip from https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/185/DX_catalog-939119.pdf]

[digkey.com Hirose DX20M-50S(50)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DX20M-50S-50/H11323-ND/1095640)

[digikey.com Hirose DX40-50P-55](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DX40-50P-55/H123261-ND/4283203)

[mouser.com](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/185/DX_catalog-939119.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Centronics 50 pin. Popular for SCSI 1

[image]

EDIT: Latches don’t match as brhans pointed out. Could be Micro DB50.

[image]

Comment: additional info from servo driver datasheet, https://ibb.co/nDXeJT

Comment: Looks much smaller & higher-density than SCSI-I, and the latches are different.

Comment: This is clearly not the same connector.